# Securing ELMAH File

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah

I am trying to allow the access to the elmah.axd file for only a perticular login and all others should be denied. I have followed Phil Haack's [tutorial](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/07/24/securely-implement-elmah-for-plug-and-play-error-logging.aspx)  for securing the file.

```
<httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
            <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="admin/elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
        </httpHandlers>

<location path="admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="admin@testing.com"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

First I logged in as **user@testing.com** and tried to access the http://localhost:58961/admin/elmah.axd file and I am rightly being redirected to the Login.aspx page. Next I logged in as **admin@testing.com** and was able to access the elmah file at http://localhost:58961/admin/elmah.axd. Now I logged in again as **user@testing.com** and I was able to access the emlah file now. What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure you logged off between the two tries. Many times an open browser window doesn't allow the cookie to expire. I would navigate to fake page junk.aspx to verify which log-on is active.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you still had a valid session key from your "admin@testing.com" account. This may have been from a browser window, or from how asp.net handles authentication.

sometime there can be a case where the asp.net authentication ticket is market as expired, however the cookie has not yet (because of sliding expiry)